# SQLite3 Import CSV & exclude/skip header

Tags: sqlite, csv, import

I'm trying to get my data files (of which there are a dozen or so) into tables within SQLite.  Each file has a header and I'll be receiving them a few times over the coming year so I'd like to:

1. Avoid editing each file to remove the header when I receive them;
2. Avoid falling back on shell scripts or Python to do this.

I define my table and import data...

```
> .separator "\t"
> .headers on
> CREATE TABLE clinical(
       patid      VARCHAR(20),
       eventdate  CHAR(10),
       sysdate    CHAR(10),
       constype   INT,
       consid     INT,
       medcode    INT,
       staffid    VARCHAR(20),
       textid     INT,
       episode    INT,
       enttype    INT,
       adid           INT);
> .import "Sample_Clinical001.txt" clinical
> SELECT * FROM clinical LIMIT 10;
patid   eventdate   sysdate constype    consid  medcode staffid textid  episode enttype adid
patid   eventdate   sysdate constype    consid  medcode staffid textid  episode enttype adid
471001  30/01/1997  09/03/1997  4   68093   180 0   0   0   20  11484
471001  30/01/1997  09/03/1997  2   68093   60  0   0   0   4   11485
```

My first thought was to DELETE the offending row, but that didn't work as expected, instead it deleted the whole table...

```
> DELETE FROM clinical WHERE patid = "patid";
> SELECT * FROM clinical LIMIT 3;
>
```

Did I get the syntax for testing equality wrong? I'm not sure; [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) don't seem to distinguish between the two. I thought I'd try again ...

```
> .import "Sample_Clinical001.txt" clinical
> SELECT * FROM clinical LIMIT 3;
patid   eventdate   sysdate constype    consid  medcode staffid textid  episode enttype adid
patid   eventdate   sysdate constype    consid  medcode staffid textid  episode enttype adid
471001  30/01/1997  09/03/1997  4   68093   180 0   0   0   20  11484
471001  30/01/1997  09/03/1997  2   68093   60  0   0   0   4   11485
> DELETE FROM clinical WHERE patid == "patid";
> SELECT * FROM clinical LIMIT 3;
>
```

Am I even on the correct track here or am I doing something stupid?

I would have expected there to be an easy option to skip the header row when calling `.import` as having header rows in text files is a fairly common situation.

Comment: You shouldn't have this problem... the first row of your csv should end up with a `INSERT failed: datatype mismatch` automatically since you have `INT` fields.

Comment: Thanks, although I solved this problem eight years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`patid` is a column name.
`"patid"` is a quoted column name.
`'patid'` is a string.

The condition `WHERE patid = "patid"` compares the value in the `patid` column with itself.

(SQLite allows strings with double quotes for compatibility with MySQL, but only where a string cannot be confused with a table/column name.)

Comment: Ah, ha!  Thanks I hadn't noticed this subtle nuance.

Comment: Just to be sure, the condition that would do the correct deletion should be WHERE patid = " 'patid' ", correct?

Comment: @gvrocha No, `" '...' "` does not make sense.

Comment: Is there still not an import option that can handle files with headers?

Comment: @martin Only when the table does not yet exist.

Comment: I found it in the documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import). It looks like for this particular question, since the data would be coming into a table from multiple csv files, deleting the header is still the only option, but in other situations, the solution could just be to skip the `CREATE TABLE` step.

Comment: correct syntax should be like this:WHERE "patid"='patid'

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
.read schema.sql
.mode csv
.import --skip 1 artist_t.csv artist_t
```

or if you just have one file to import, you can do it like this:

```
.import --csv --skip 1 artist_t.csv artist_t
```

https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files

Answer (score 1):

A alternative response to @steven-penny

You can also use a bash command during sqlite import

```
.mode csv
.import '| tail -n +2 artist_t.csv' artist_t
```